# Помогите переписать программу с basic на pascal

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, basic

Я совсем не знаком с бейсиком, помогите переписать программу построения графика функции y = sin (x) * x.

```
Rem График функции
CLS
Screen 9
Color 2
h = .1
xnach = -5 : xkon = 5
n = INT((xkon – xnach) / h)
ymin = sin (xnach) * xnach : xmin = xnach
ymax = sin (xnach) * xnach : xmax = xnach
FOR x = xnach TO xkon STEP h
y = sin (x) * x
IF y < ymin THEN ymin = y : xmin = x
IF y > ymax THEN ymax = y : xmax = x
NEXT x
PRINT “ymax = ”; ymax
PRINT “ymin = ”; ymin
Rem Вычисление масштаба по оси x
mx = 600 / (xmax - xmin)
Rem Вычисление масштаба по оси y
my = 300 / (ymax - ymin)
PRINT “mx = ”; mx
PRINT “my = ”; my
Rem Оси координат
LINE (10, 301) – (630, 301), 2
LINE (320, 10) – (320, 301), 2
LOCATE 22, 78 : PRINT “> x”
LOCATE 1, 41 : PRINT “ ^ y”
COLOR 14 : LOCATE 2, 10 : PRINT “График функции”
Rem Нанесение точек графика на координатную плоскость
FOR x = xnach TO xkon STEP h
y = sin (x) * x
PSET (320 + (x*mx) / 10 , 300 – y* my ), 4
IF y > ymax THEN ymax = y : xmax = x
NEXT x
END
```

Вот что получилось у меня, но код не работает корректно

```pascal
uses GraphABC;
var h, xnach, xkon, n, xmin, xmax, x, mx, my: integer;
     ymin, ymax, y: real;
 
begin
  
  h := 1;
  xnach := -5;
  xkon := 5;
  n := integer(((xkon - xnach) / h));
  
  ymin := sin (xnach) * xnach;
  xmin := xnach;
  ymax := sin (xnach) * xnach;
  xmax := xnach;
  
  for x:=xnach to xkon step h do
    begin
    y := sin(x)*x;
    if y < ymin then
      begin
        ymin := y;
        xmin := x;
      end;
    if y > ymax then
      begin
        ymax := y;
        xmax := x;
      end;
    end;
  
  writeln('ymax= ', ymax);
  writeln('ymin= ', ymin);
  
  mx := integer(600/(xmax - xmin));
  my := integer(300/(ymax - ymin));
  
  writeln('mx= ', mx);
  writeln('my= ', my);
  
  line((10, 301),(630, 301));
  line((320, 10),(320, 301));
  
  for x:=xnach to xkon step h do
    begin
      y := integer(sin(x)*x);
      SetPixel(integer(320+(x*mx)/10),integer(300-y*my),rgb(0,0,0));
      if y > ymax then
        begin
          ymax := y;
          xmax := x;
        end;
    end;
 
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте h сделать real и присвоить 0,1. должно стать лучше

Comment: Тогда циклы работать не будут, т.к. h вещественное, а нужно целое

Comment: Тогда циклы надо переделать на while

Comment: Переписал с while, но стало еще хуже https://pastebin.com/WtgwCYjw

Comment: в строках 9 и 10 сделайте -5 и 5, и в строке 51 без integer  y := sin(x)*x;

Comment: Спасибо большое! Если в строках 9 и 10 сделать -10 и 10 то выглядит еще лучше